# Backbone.js wrapper template for a Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My Backbone app is going to have multiple objects of a Collection, each collection containing multiple models. What I'd like to do is to have each Collection object wrapped into a div element, and a custom title depending on the collection object attribute value.

At the moment Collection is utilizing views for the models and doesn't contain any of its own template.

What would be the best approach to wrap each collection object into a template?

Update:

Here is how my CollectionView looks like at the moment:

```
window.OrderListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#all-orders-container',
    template: _.template(orderListTpl),
    initialize: function() {
      this.$el.append(this.template({order_id: this.collection.order_id}));
    },
    render: function(){
        var _this = this;
        this.collection.forEach(this.addItem, this);
    },
    addItem: function(orderItem){
        var orderView = new OrderView({
            model: orderItem
        });

        this.$el.append(orderView.render());
    }
  });
```

There will be multiple objects of the same CollectionView class. The problem now is - how to render those into a separate elements, and also append new orderView elements into a proper elements?

Comment: You can explain some example for your collection what contain objects of multiple models?

Comment: Backbone collection intended to organize objects of **specific model**, otherwise it is not exactly backbone collection

Comment: But I should be able to have multiple objects of the same Collection, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a collection view like this

```
var CollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({

    render:function(){
        var _this = this;
        this.collection.each(function(model){
            _this.addItem(model)
        })
    },
    addItem:function(model){
        var itemView = new ItemView({
            model:model
        });

        itemView.render().$el.appendTo(this.$el);

    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks this is a good hint. However there will be a multiple objects of this CollectionView, and I wonder how to pass proper root element to the $el of this particular CollectionView. Or I should probably alter the value of $el on CollectionView initialization to create a new one every time?

Comment: @AlexanderSavin I am not very sure what is question in above comment, if it is about assigning $el to CollectionView, you can do that while instantiating CollectionView like `var collView = new CollectionView({el:'your selector'})`

Comment: Yes, I've resolved this now by manually generating the el for every CollectionView object. Not very elegant, but it works!

Comment: I don't whether you know it already, if you don't specify el for a view, it will create it's own. You need not to create on, check out `_ensureElement` function in backbone source, you might get better idea of what happens when you skip el